# ERR Error compiling script (new function): user_script:1: unexpected symbol near ')'

Tags: stackexchange.redis

I have installed StackExchange as a Redis Client for my API using C#, I followed all the steps in this tutorial : http://tostring.it/2015/04/23/An-easy-way-to-use-StackExchange-Redis%20copy/

When I make a request to the server I receive this error :

Message: "An error has occurred.",

```
    ExceptionMessage: "ERR Error compiling script (new function): user_script:1: unexpected symbol near ')' ",

    ExceptionType: "StackExchange.Redis.RedisServerException",

    StackTrace: " a StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.ExecuteSyncImpl[T](Message message ResultProcessor`1 processor, ServerEndPoint server) in      c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\3ae0647004edff78\StackExchange.Redis\StackExchange\R edis\ConnectionMultiplexer.cs:line 1935
    at StackExchange.Redis.RedisBase.ExecuteSync[T](Message message,ResultProcessor`1 processor, ServerEndPoint server) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\3ae0647004edff78\StackExchange.Redis\StackExchange\Redis\RedisBase.cs:line 80at StackExchange.Redis.RedisDatabase.ScriptEvaluate(String script, RedisKey[]    keys, RedisValue[] values, CommandFlags flags)
```

in   c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\3ae0647004edff78\StackExchange.Redis\StackExchange\Redis\RedisDatabase.cs:line 873
        at StackExchange.Redis.Extensions.Core.StackExchangeRedisCacheClient.GetAll[T](IEnumerable`1 keys)

I recieved this error when I post. Could please advice , thank you kindly

Comment: I've logged an issues against [StackExchange.Redis.Extensions](https://github.com/imperugo/StackExchange.Redis.Extensions/issues/20), but note: this is not part of StackExchange.Redis itself.

Comment: Submitted PR #21 as a possible fix. https://github.com/imperugo/StackExchange.Redis.Extensions/pull/21

Comment: Thank you, I was using the ConnectionMultiplexer incorrectly because I was not aware that it was separate from StackEchange.Redis. I've got it working now.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably this error is coming from the 3rd party code(StackExchange.Redis.Extensions, which is not part of StackExchange.Redis - it simply uses it) generating invalid Lua in the `CreateLuaScriptForMget` method. It isn't obvious to me *why* it is doing any of this, since there is already a varadic `mget` method that would do this *correctly*, without touching Lua at any point. I'm not going to try to fix the 3rd-party code, but if I was: I'd be replacing any code that uses `CreateLuaScriptForMget` with, instead code that uses the `RedisValue[] IDatabase.StringGet(RedisKey[] keys, ...)` API, which will use `mget` internally.

Answer (score 0):

I've changed the methods for AddAll/GetAll removing Lua script and using StringGet/StringSet with the specific array ([here](https://github.com/imperugo/StackExchange.Redis.Extensions/commit/e733463060186883524e2fbdecb7f7f817a7ce52) the commit)

It's deployed on Nuget [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/StackExchange.Redis.Extensions.Core/1.1.13)
The problem should be fixed, let me know.

Thanks for the support